# ECS cluster name with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to deploy an ECS cluster on AWS with CloudFormation, but I can't figure out how to set the cluster a custom name.

The cluster is created, but with somehow generated name, with format like `stackname-ECSCluster-randomstring`.

Is there a way how to set a custom name for the cluster?

The [AWS::ECS::Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html) doesn't accept any parameters or tags, nor the [AWS::ECS:Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html).

It's kind of cosmetic thing, but it would be nice to have meaningfull names.

Answer (score 6):

Clipped directly from my CloudFormation scripts.  If you want to pass it in, you can do so as a parameter.  Specifying the name may have been something that was added since you wrote the post.  Either way, this works for me.

```
Resources:
  MyCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: TheNameOfTheCluster
```

If you want to mangle the name of the cluster you can use [Fn::Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) to join two (or more) strings.  The following will result in a cluster named "MyClusterNamePrefix-MyClusterNameSuffix"

```
Resources:
  MyCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Join
        - "-"    # The delimiter String
        - - MyClusterNamePrefix
          - MyClusterNameSuffix
```

If you ever need the name back out of it you can reference elsewhere, they don't make that easy.  I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but chances are you may need to reference the name elsewhere (*eg* UserData).

```
Outputs:
  MyClusterName:
    Description: The Name of My Cluster
    Value:
      Fn::Select:
        - 1
        - Fn::Split:
          - "/"
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - MyCluster
```

This is because (at the time of this writing) [Fn::GetAtt](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) can only return the Cluster's ARN (scroll down to the table of supported attributes).  The specification for ECS Cluster ARNs is as follows:

```
arn:aws:ecs:region:account-id:cluster/cluster-name
```

So, putting it all together:

- [Fn::Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) splits on "/", discards the delimiter, and returns the ["arn:aws:ecs:region:account-id:cluster", "cluster-name"]
- [Fn::Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) allows you to select from the list of strings.  So passing '1' returns just "cluster-name".

Port to JSON as needed.  It's kind of an ugly approach to it, but it works.  I would keep an eye out for if/when Amazon can actually expose that as an attribute and update your code.

Answer (score 3):

CloudFormation does not allow you to set a custom name today.  If you want to use a specific name, you can create the cluster outside CloudFormation and just reference it inside the template.